# Inserting large delimited string with multiple values and rows into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, csv

I have a delimited string that I will be passing into a stored procedure that I would like to split into multiple entries in a database.

the string would look like "1,1a,1b;2,2a,2b;3,3a,3b" but with a few hundred entries

I want it to be inserted into a table like the rendering below:
(I apologize I can't figure out how to draw a table here so I have created an html representation of what I am looking for.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1a</td>
    <td>1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2a</td>
    <td>2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3a</td>
    <td>3b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this in SQL Server?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: How do you know how many elements are on a single row of your table?

Comment: There is a different character to distinguish the end of an element.  I have a semi-colon in my example.

Comment: how are you planning to handle commas in the data (a really common character)...and semi-colors for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Solution using XML method.

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE @x AS XML=''
DECLARE @Param AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,1a,1b;2,2a,2b;3,3a,3b' /* Your Delimited String INPUT */
SET @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@Param,';','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)
SELECT t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') Value INTO #temp FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)
;With CTE
AS
(
    SELECT * ,  CAST(('<r><n>' + REPLACE([Value],',', '</n><n>') + '</n></r>') AS XML) X
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT [Value] ,
 i.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS col1,
 i.value('n[2]','VARCHAR(50)') AS col2,
 i.value('n[3]','VARCHAR(50)') AS col3
 FROM CTE c
CROSS APPLY c.X.nodes('/r') x(i)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Value      col1            col2         col3 
---------- --------------- ------------ ---- 
1,1a,1b    1               1a           1b   
2,2a,2b    2               2a           2b   
3,3a,3b    3               3a           3b   

(3 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a string splitter for this. There are plenty of out there, however, the one I'm using in the below example is Jeff Moden's [Delimited Split 8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/); if you have a preference then use that one.

This also, **assumes** you are only expecting 3 columns, as you have defined in your sample:

```
DECLARE @DS varchar(8000);
SET @DS = '1,1a,1b;2,2a,2b;3,3a,3b';

SELECT LEFT(Item, CI1.CI - 1) AS Col1,
       SUBSTRING(Item, CI1.CI + 1, CI2.CI - CI1.CI - 1) As Col2,
       RIGHT(Item, LEN(Item) - CI2.CI) AS Col3
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (@DS,';') DR
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',DR.Item))) CI1(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',DR.Item, CI1.CI + 1))) CI2(CI);
```

Comment: I see this only takes an varchar 8000.  Is there an option that does nvarchar(max)?

Comment: There are plenty out there that do, yes. That was just the splitter that I have on my Sandbox server. If you do have a varchar over 8,000, or an nvarchar over 4,000 though, I would seriously reconsider your storage method.